# Android: Unfortunately App has stopped running Layout Issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to call a class I have created in my activity, unfortunately, as soon as click on a button that is supposed to send me to my activity, the app stops running. I have tried to debug it and it always stops at the line setContentView(R.layout.activity_draw_triangle). I have looked online and tried to resolve my problem with the different answers available, but nothing to do.

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.PathMeasure;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Path;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import scribens.zarha.scribensapp.DrawingView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class DrawTriangleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        DrawingView dv;
        TextView instructions;
        private ArrayList<Path> pointsToDraw = new ArrayList<Path>();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_draw_triangle);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        instructions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        dv = (DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.dv);
        dv = new DrawingView(this);
        //setContentView(dv);

     }



    public void GoBack(View view) {
        // Brings the user to the activity where the draw a line
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the class that I have created

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

import android.view.View;
import android.util.AttributeSet;


    public class DrawingView extends View {

        private Path mPath;
        private Paint mPaint;
        private Bitmap mBitmap;
        private Canvas mCanvas;
        public int width;
        public  int height;
        private Paint mBitmapPaint;
        Context context;
        private Paint circlePaint;
        private Path circlePath;


        public DrawingView(Context c) {
            super(c);
            context=c;
            setupDrawing();
        }

        private void setupDrawing(){
        //get drawing area setup for interaction
            mPath = new Path();
            mPaint = new Paint();
            circlePaint = new Paint();
            circlePath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setDither(true);
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);

            circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
            circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //draw view
            canvas.drawBitmap( mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            canvas.drawPath( mPath,  mPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(circlePath,  circlePaint);
        }

        public float mX, mY;
        public static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        public void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;

        }

        public void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;

                circlePath.reset();
                circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
            }
        }

        public void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            circlePath.reset();
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath,  mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            mPath.reset();

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }


    }
```

Finally, my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="mygod.myname.mygodapp.DrawActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Suivez le tracé du triangle"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <mygod.myname.mygodapp.DrawingView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="222dp"
        android:id="@+id/dv" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Retour"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="GoBack"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Stack code

```
07-18 15:55:56.003 28620-28620/mygod.myname.mygodapp W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x01080af7 (t=7 e=2807) (error -75)
07-18 15:55:56.083 28620-28620/mygod.myname.mygodapp D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
07-18 15:55:56.083 28620-28620/mygod.myname.mygodapp D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
07-18 15:55:56.133 28620-28620/mygod.myname.mygodapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-18 15:55:56.333 28620-28746/mygod.myname.mygodapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
07-18 15:55:56.353 28620-28620/mygod.myname.mygodapp V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{1fd2b97 token=android.os.BinderProxy@3dde6f31 {mygod.myname.mygodapp/mygod.myname.mygodapp.MainActivity}} show : true
07-18 15:55:56.353 28620-28620/mygod.myname.mygodapp D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
07-18 15:55:56.353 28620-28620/mygod.myname.mygodapp D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
07-18 15:55:56.383 28620-28620/mygod.myname.mygodapp D/SRIB_DCS: log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
07-18 15:55:56.383 28620-28746/mygod.myname.mygodapp I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
                                                                        OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.06
                                                                        Build Date: 06/05/15 Fri
                                                                        Local Branch: LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.01.00.042.032
                                                                        Remote Branch: 
                                                                        Local Patches: 
                                                                        Reconstruct Branch: 
07-18 15:55:56.383 28620-28746/mygod.myname.mygodapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-18 15:55:56.403 28620-28746/mygod.myname.mygodapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Get maximum texture size. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 4096
07-18 15:55:56.403 28620-28746/mygod.myname.mygodapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
07-18 15:55:56.553 28620-28620/mygod.myname.mygodapp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3dde6f31 time:188182652
07-18 15:55:56.553 28620-28620/mygod.myname.mygodapp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3dde6f31 time:188182652
07-18 15:55:59.833 28620-28620/mygod.myname.mygodapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
07-18 15:55:59.893 28620-28620/mygod.myname.mygodapp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:mygod.myname.mygodapp time:188185997
07-18 15:55:59.943 28620-28620/mygod.myname.mygodapp W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x01080af7 (t=7 e=2807) (error -75)
07-18 15:55:59.953 28620-28620/mygod.myname.mygodapp D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
07-18 15:55:59.953 28620-28620/mygod.myname.mygodapp D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
07-18 15:55:59.963 28620-28620/mygod.myname.mygodapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-18 15:55:59.963 28620-28620/mygod.myname.mygodapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: mygod.myname.mygodapp, PID: 28620
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mygod.myname.mygodapp/mygod.myname.mygodapp.DrawTriangleActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class mygod.myname.mygodapp.DrawingView
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3124)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3233)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6873)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class mygod.myname.mygodapp.DrawingView
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                at mygod.myname.mygodapp.DrawTriangleActivity.onCreate(DrawTriangleActivity.java:38)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3077)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3233) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6873) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
                                                                                at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
                                                                                at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:495)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                at mygod.myname.mygodapp.DrawTriangleActivity.onCreate(DrawTriangleActivity.java:38) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3077) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3233) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6873) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
```

Comment: Don't post crashing problems without the stack trace

Comment: Just posted it sorry for the delay ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DrawingView needs a constructor DrawingView(Context, AttributeSet).  THis is what's called when inflating from xml (the various parameters are the attribute set). You should also have a DrawingView(Context, AttributeSet, int) just in case of theming.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I figured I needed an attribute set. But when I call the following line : 

`dv = new DrawingView(this);`

I dont know what to put as a value in the variable attrs,

So should i modify the parameters in the XML to consider these my attribute sets based on your answer?

Comment: It actually says that DrawingView context attribute set cannot be applied to DrawActivity

Comment: You're putting it in the wrong file then.  It needs to go in the DrawingView class.

Comment: But then how do I call my DrawingView class from my DrawActivity activity?

Answer (score 0):

In the onCreate() use button.onClickLIstner() and inside onclick listner add the code for intent.

Comment: Not so sure I understand what you mean by the code for intent?

Comment: This in no way will solve your problem. You need to post the stack trace of the given error.

Comment: Just posed the stack :)